# WebDriverIO + Mocha + Unable to click on Toggle element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to automate a chat application build on React using **[WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io)** and Mocha as the test framework.

I am facing an issue while clicking on a toggle display element. I tried `browser.click(<XPathSelector>)` command at various stages, but was not able to achieve it.

There are no `id` or `name` attributes associated with the element.
Please let me know if anyone is aware of how I can accomplish this!

Comment: show the xpath locator . show the code

Comment: Unless you provide us with a **[Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** no one will be able to help you. Basically provide the `html` snippet that contains your targeted element, the code you tried and a short description of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
`browser.click('Xpathselector');` or you can use a class from element like
`browser.click('class');` example `browser.click('.delete-class');`